# Hystrix Request Cache And Parallel Streams

Tags: java, caching, hystrix

Is it possible to use both hystrix request caching and parallel streams at the same time?

For example, I am initialising the hystrix request context in a servlet filter in my web app. The endpoint is processing multiple entries each of which will call a method that is wrapped in a hystrix command with caching enabled. When run sequentially, it works as expected. When run in a parallel stream ie.

```
things.stream().parallel().map(thing -> hytrsixCommand(thing))
```

Then it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request caching is not available. Maybe you need to initialize the HystrixRequestContext?
```

Is there a way to pass the hystrix request context down from the initial calling thread to the child threads created by the parallel stream?